# How to remove dependencies of order in Json schema in case of Array of objects

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I have one Json schema template, which contains array of objects. And I need to verify Json input with that template. But I want this should not dependent on order for object in array.

And below we have array of 3 different object in template i.e. abs, endpoint and dispatch. I want to remove dependency of order from here. I can provide ant order of items in Json input schema. It should not dependent on template. I am using 'ajv' node js template to validate the Json input with template data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Attached template and input json.

Json Template

var schema1 = {
  "additionalProperties" : {
    "type" : "integer"
  },
    "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "string" },
        "description": { "type": "string" },
        "services": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": { "type": "string", "const" :"abs" },
                        "id": { "type": "string" },
                        "name": { "type": "string" },
                        "appId": { "type": "string" },
                        "endpoint": { "type": "string" }
                    },
                    //"additionalProperties": false
                    "required": [  "type","id", "name","appId", "endpoint"]
                },
                {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                      "type": { "type": "string", "const" :"endpoint" },
                      "id": { "type": "string" },
                      "name": { "type": "string" },
                      "appPassword": { "type": "string" },
                      "appId": { "type": "string" },
                      "endpoint": { "type": "string" }
                  },
                  //"additionalProperties": false,
                  "required": [  "type","id", "name","appPassword","appId", "endpoint"]
               }
               ,
               {
                 "type": "object",
                 "properties": {
                     "type": { "type": "string", "const" :"dispatch" },
                     "serviceIds" : {"type":"array", "items": [{ "type": "string" }]},
                     "name": { "type": "string" },
                     "appId": { "type": "string" },
                     "authoringKey": { "type": "string" },
                     "version": { "type": "string" },
                     "region": { "type": "string" },
                     "id": { "type": "string" }
                 },
                 //"additionalProperties": false
                 "required": [  "type","serviceIds", "name","appId","authoringKey","version","region", "id"]
              }
            ]
        }
    }
};


Input Json :

 {
  "name": "ScorpioBot-development",
  "description": "",
  "services": [

      {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "development",
            "appId": "test",
            "appPassword": "test",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978"
        },
        {
          "type": "abs",
          "id": "49",
          "name": "test-development",
          "appId": "12323",
          "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/"
      },
        {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "id": "11",
            "name": "development",
            "appId": "test1",
            "appPassword": "test1",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978"
        },
        {
            "type": "dispatch",
            "serviceIds": [
                "general"
            ],
            "name": "test_Dispatch",
            "appId": "test",
            "authoringKey": "1234,
            "version": "Dispatch",
            "region": "test",
            "id": "dispatch"
        }
  ]
}` {
  "name": "ScorpioBot-development",
  "description": "",
  "services": [

      {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "development",
            "appId": "test",
            "appPassword": "test",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978"
        },
        {
          "type": "abs",
          "id": "49",
          "name": "test-development",
          "appId": "12323",
          "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/"
      },
        {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "id": "11",
            "name": "development",
            "appId": "test1",
            "appPassword": "test1",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978"
        },
        {
            "type": "dispatch",
            "serviceIds": [
                "general"
            ],
            "name": "test_Dispatch",
            "appId": "test",
            "authoringKey": "1234,
            "version": "Dispatch",
            "region": "test",
            "id": "dispatch"
        }
  ]
}`
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript, i think this should help you.

Comment: I believe the above comment has missunderstood the question. I think the asker is saying their array may be any of a specific set of item types.

Comment: I notice you also posted the same question on the JSON Schema Google Group (which I approved). You are more likely to get answers by posting here, as the community activly monitors and is alerted to the `jsonschema` tag.

Answer (score 3):

The `items` keyword takes either a single schema, or an array or schemas.

If you provide an array of schemas, the 1st schema must is applied to the 1st item in the array, and then the 2nd schema is applied to the 2nd item in the array, etc for n schemas and items.

To change your schema so that the value of `items` is a single schema, wrap your array of schemas in an `oneOf`. This will mean that each item in the array must be valid for one of the schemas in the array value of `oneOf`.